# Custom css is not rendered correctly in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, django-templates, jinja2

I have updated the base url of the flask application.

### app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route(f'{root}' + '/')
def index():
........
.......
return render_template('index.html')
```

### Application directory structure:

```
/app
   /static
       /style.css
   /template
       /index.html
   app.py
```

I have placed my custom style.css file under static folder.
When i ran the application under console in developer tools there is an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amRvi.png) which is not allowing to render the style.css

error: `https://domain/static/style.css`

The actual url has to point `https://domain/f'{root}'/static/style.css`

### the code in index.html:

To access style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
```

**Question**
How to redirect the style.css url as mentioned above `https://domain/f'{root}'/static/style.css` without modifying the style.css directory path ?

**Help would be appreciated, Thanks**

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/ and configured `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: My application is on Flask not on Django

Comment: my bad, you can set the path via `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='...')`

Comment: I have tried this but not working out in my scenario.

Comment: You should include your definition of the Flask app in your question

Comment: I have edited app.py file code. Please have a look @Jan Wilamowski

Comment: your code doesn't set `static_url_path` at all, of course that won't work

Comment: Yes, It is not working with "static_url_path". So, i didn't placed the argument in Edited code.